How to serialize a dynamic object field in Jackson that can be null, "void", or varying data structures?
I'm trying to serialize an EventData model as a string using Jackson's ObjectMapper. The EventData model contains various fields, including custom objects, and one specific field called response of type Object. The purpose of this field is to store versatile API responses, which can vary in structure since the responses don't share common fields. Therefore, the response field is defined as Object.
The challenge I'm facing is that the response field can sometimes be null, sometimes a string with the value "void", and other times it can be a completely different data structure. While my current ObjectMapper setup handles null and "void" cases correctly, it fails when the response contains more complex or different data structures, causing the serialization to fail. How can I handle these varying types in the response field and ensure that they are serialized properly into a string?
String convert(String objectName, Object object) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES);

    try {
        if (object == null) {
            return "void";
        }

        // Check if the response is a string that literally says "void"
        if (object instanceof String && object.equals("void")) {
            return "void";
        }

        // Check if the object is a Jakarta Response object (or its subclass)
        if (object instanceof jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response) {
            jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response response = (jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response) object;

            // Extract the entity (body) from the response
            Object entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity == null) {
                return "void"; // Handle case where there's no entity
            } else {
                // Serialize the entity (not the full Response object)
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
            }
        }

        // Continue with normal serialization for other objects
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // If serialization fails, log the error or return a placeholder
        return objectName + "...:::CONVERSION_FAILURE:::";
    }
}


An example of the classes that cause failures and the actual error message would be useful.
